# if $a$ is are real number that $a \neq 0$, and $\cos x = \sqrt{\frac{\cot x}{\cot x -a^2}}$, $x$ is on which trigonometric quadrants?

Tags: trigonometry

> if $a$ is are real number that $a \neq  0$, and $\cos x = \sqrt{\frac{\cot x}{\cot x -a^2}}$, $x$ is on which trigonometric quadrants?

Things I have done so far: this problem is mostly different from that I previously solved.My Idea was to powering up both sides,take all to one side and then solve it like equation.which I was not successful. any starting hint would be appreciated as I don't looking for full solution.

**UPDATE**

thanks to ganeshie8 hints,i reached this right now$$\cos^2a=1+\sin a\times \cos a$$

And I stuck here.

Comment: squaring and trying to solve $x$ is a good start ! you might have figured out already :  $\cos x$ is positive only in $I$ and $IV$ quadrants

Comment: @ganeshie8,thanks for your hint.i think there is a problem.this question is originally from a test.so answer could be just one quadrant.but both $I$ and $IV$ are possible because both of them result positive ${\frac{\cot x}{\cot x -a^2}}$ so $\cos x$ would be positive .do i missing something?

Comment: squaring gives you an equation which can be factored easily, solving it should eliminate one of the quadrants

Comment: you should end up with $a^2\sin x+\cos x = 0  \implies   \cot x  =  -a^2$ which eliminates quadrant  $I$ since $\cot x$ is not negative in quadrant $I$

Comment: small correction  :  $a^2\cos x + \sin x  = 0 \implies \tan x  = -a^2  $

Comment: @ganeshie8,thanks,i tried what you said but i stuck.could please you look at the post(i updated it)?

Comment: looks there is a minor mistake in your equation, but the moment you see the form $\cos^2x = 1 + \text{something}$, you should try to replace $1-\cos^2x$ by $\sin^2x$

Comment: $\cos^2x =  \dfrac{\cot x}{\cot x - a^2} \implies \cos x (\cot x - a^2) = 1/\sin x  \implies  \cos x(\cos x - a^2\sin x) = 1 \implies   a^2\sin x \cos x = \cos^2 x - 1 \implies  a^2 \cos x =  -\sin x \cdots $

Comment: The first quadrant is not possible. No algebraic manipulation is needed.  For if $\cot x\gt a^2$, then $\frac{\cot x}{\cot x-a^2}\gt 1$, so the square root is greater than $1$, impossible for a cosine. And if $a^2\gt \cot x$, we end up taking the square root of a negative number.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you mean it is impossible for forth quadrant?well $\cot x$ is also negative, so the hole fraction will be positive.did i missed any of your points?

Comment: The fourth quadrant is not ruled out. For in the fourth quadrant, $\cot x\le 0$, and therefore $0\le \frac{\cot x}{\cot x-a^2}\lt 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation has the first quadrant solution $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Apart from that,  the first quadrant is not possible. Note that if $x\ne \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $x$ is in the first quadrant, and $\cot x$ is defined, then $\cot x\gt 0$.

Thus if $\cot x\gt a^2$, then $0\lt \cot x-a^2\lt \cot x$, and therefore  $\frac{\cot x}{\cot x-a^2}\gt 1$. So our square root is greater than $1$, which is impossible for a cosine.

And if $a^2\gt \cot x$, we are taking the square root of a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

We are given: 
$$\cos x = \sqrt{\frac{\cot x}{\cot x - a^2}}$$

For this to be true,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\cot x}{\cot x - a^2}} \in [-1,1]$$
Now, for any$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} \in \mathbb R, \quad a>0 ,\quad b>0$

For the first condition ($a>0$),
$$ \implies \cot x > 0
\implies \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} >0\\
\implies (2n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}<x<(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} \text{ and } x \ne 0 \quad \forall \space n \in \mathbb Z$$
This means that $x$ is in  Quadrants I or IV.

For the second condition ($b>0$),
$$\implies \cot x - a^2 > 0 $$

We can now clearly see that 
$$\cot x > \cot x - a^2 > 0\\
\implies \text{Numerator} > \text{Denominator}\\
\implies \frac{\cot x}{\cot x - a^2} > 1$$

But this is against our initial assumption.

The only solution is $\frac{\pi}{2} \space\implies x \in $ Ist Quadrant

Comment: this problem driven me crazy.$\frac{- \pi}{2}$ could be a solution also.So $\sin(\frac{- \pi}{2})=sin(\frac{3 \pi}{2})$.So forth is acceptable.